# How to change the button colors when button is clicked?

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app the has choices. I want to know what button was clicked so I want to change the color of the clicked button here is my XML selector code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:color="#182f57"/> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:color="#4e8fcf"/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:color="#4e8fcf"/> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

Here is my XML activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#D6EAF8"
tools:context=".AssessmentActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:layout_width="373dp"
    android:layout_height="132dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:typeface="normal"
    app:fontFamily="sans"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.421"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/none"
    android:layout_width="189dp"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:background="@drawable/clicked_button"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/mild"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/results" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mild"
    android:layout_width="189dp"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:background="#4e8fcf"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/moderate"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/none" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/moderate"
    android:layout_width="189dp"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:background="#4e8fcf"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/severe"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mild" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/severe"
    android:layout_width="189dp"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:background="#4e8fcf"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/very"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/moderate" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/very"
    android:layout_width="189dp"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:background="#4e8fcf"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnresult"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/severe" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/results"
    android:layout_width="375dp"
    android:layout_height="142dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/question"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnresult"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#4e8fcf"
    android:text="Result"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.071"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.973" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#4e8fcf"
    android:text="Menu"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.973" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/usersname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#D6EAF8"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/moderate"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.296"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/results"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.959" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see I tried to change one button. This line

```
android:background="@drawable/clicked_button"
```

and this is what happened

[image: XML Design]

The button color was not set.

Comment: Did you try this after compile or on a device? That's just the AS preview so, it can be visible on the runtime. However, no need to mention that it works **when button** clicked-pressed on the runtime.

Comment: i tried to run the app but i got android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class Button
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)

Comment: And what happens if you remove: `@drawable/clicked_button` ? I think the problem is the drawable.

Comment: the button will be set to default

Comment: im getting infalting class button

Answer (score 0):

I made like this one.

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_sign_in"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
                android:text="@string/button_sign_in"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText" />
```

Make a new drawable resource file. 
for example: button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

In onclick method set button color in following ways

```
Button_ID.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // From android.graphics.Color
```

or

```
Button_ID.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000); // 0xAARRGGBB
```